# Encode webservice API url

Tags: web-services, security, web, encoding

I am using multiple webservices API from multiple clients. 
I can see the URL in the network tab in the browser inspect. i don't want to  expose the URL.

Is there any way to encode the URL to unread format?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From client side, no way. Maybe use a gateway url which does server-side call to "wanna be hidden" url and returns its result to the client ? But it wouldn't change the fact the output would be the same.

if you want to hide an url call from the client, don't do it client-side.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your design , essentially you need to put a proxy layer in between your client and actual API where the proxy can take a generic input with the encrypted url as the parameter something like

/Apiproxy/{encrypted url}

And the proxy can decrypt it and sent it to the actual u. You do have the complexity of managing the encryption key as well with this approach.

But why do you need this thing ?